# I get this error in Xcode 15 /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib?

Tags: ios, apple-m1, xcode15, macos-sonoma

All was working fine with my iOS App before updating my M1 to Sonoma and Xcode 15.

Now I get this error

> Build input file cannot be found: '/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib'. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it?

and I'm not able to solve it.

All I could find are fairly old answers that don't work. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @daniel have you gone through your build settings and looked for `libstdc++`?

Comment: Can you post your Build Settings and look for "other link flags"?  libstdc++ should be normally be added with "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content" section.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering in Xcode after updating to Sonoma and Xcode 15, where it cannot find /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib, is likely because this particular version of the C++ standard library has been deprecated and is not included in the latest macOS and Xcode versions. Here are some potential solutions you can try:

1. Change the Compiler's C++ Standard Library:
   The libstdc++ library has been deprecated in favor of libc++. You should change your project's settings to use libc++ instead of libstdc++. This can be done by updating the C++ Standard Library setting in your project's build settings to libc++.
2. Check for Excluded Architectures:
   Sometimes, an architecture such as arm64 may be automatically excluded in the build settings for your target, leading to such errors. You can try to remove the excluded architecture in your Xcode project settings under "Build settings" > "Excluded Architectures" and remove any that are listed there.
3. Check Third-party Libraries:
   If your project is using third-party libraries that depend on libstdc++, you might need to update those libraries or contact the maintainers for an updated version that uses libc++.